# Attribute table appearance in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-2

How can i display an attribute table so it does not disappear from the screen, so i work on an open map and see the attribute table simultaneously?

When i work on a map and has also opened attribute table, the attribute table disappear when i return to work on the map.

I can minimized the map screen and work with the attribute table simultaneously,

[image]
but i prefer to work on a map with on a full screen. Is there a way to to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Open attribute table in a dock window` from `Setting -> Options`

[image]

It will be displayed like this:

[image]

**Update for QGIS 3.X**

In QGIS 3.4.5 it is possible to dock/undock the attribute table directly from the table without going to the `Settings -> Options` as illustrated below:

[image]

Comment: i get this note:  "Paste features: no features could be successfully pasted."

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: QGIS version 2.18

Comment: I am wondering what is the relation of the message you got of "Pasting features" with the opening the attribute table in dock. You should right-click on the layer in the table of content and select open attribute table, which will open the attribute table in dock. That's all.